# How to add geopoint array, via PDO to crate*

Tags: php, pdo, crate

I have crateio set up and it's working fine using the PDO class.

I'm, trying to get a set of geopoints into the db using binds.

I have tried foreach but doesn't seem to work, I've tried this - which also doesn't work.

The geopoint column is set to geo_point_array.

```
$route="[[30.33333, -6.13336],[30.33333, -6.13336]]"; 

$db = new Database; 

$db->Query("insert into geopoints (id, longlat, name) values ('33',?,'pat')"); 

$db->bind(1, $route); 
$db->execute();
```

How do I add this set of cordinates to the db?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

[GeoPoint](https://crate.io/docs/en/latest/sql/data_types.html#geo-point) is not supported as a native type in Crate's PDO driver yet, however you can use an double [ARRAY](https://github.com/crate/crate-pdo/blob/master/src/Crate/PDO/PDO.php#L39).

From the Crate documentation:

> Columns with the geo_point are represented and inserted using a double
>   array in the following format: [lon_value, lat_value]

I also strongly recommend to do parameter substitution for the other values.

```
use Crate\PDO\PDO;

$route = [[30.33333, -6.13336], [30.33333, -6.13336]];

$db = new PDO('crate:...'); 
$stmt = $db->query("insert into geopoints (id, longlat, name) values (?, ?, ?)"); 

$stmt->bind(1, 33, PDO::PARAM_INT); 
$stmt->bind(2, $route, PDO::PARAM_ARRAY); 
$stmt->bind(3, 'pat', PDO::PARAM_STR); 

$stmt->execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

`PDO::query` returns `PDOStatement`:

```
$route="[[30.33333, -6.13336],[30.33333, -6.13336]]"; 

//If Dateabase is a sublcass of PDO
//$db = new Database; 
$db = new PDO(...); 

$stmt = $db->query("insert into geopoints (id, longlat, name) values ('33',?,'pat')"); 

$stmt->bind(1, $route, PDO::PARAM_STR); 
$stmt->execute();
```